# Memory profiler for .NET Compact Framework

Tags: .net, memory, compact-framework, profiling, profiler

Is there a tool I could use for profiling (memory) a .NET compact framework 3.5 application (Windows Mobile)?

*Thanks!*

Answer (score 7):

Use the [Remote Performance Monitor](http://blogs.msdn.com/stevenpr/archive/2006/04/17/577636.aspx) that comes with Studio.  It gives snapshots of the GC heap, traceable roots and much more.

Comment: It just gives you a bunch of useless information. How can anyone possibly use this to find which parts of your code are being memory hogs or have memory leaks?

Comment: I've used it on several occasions and gotten valuable info from its output.  Sure, you have to understand how to read its root graphs and trace back allocations, but once you get your hands around that, it's quite useful.

Answer (score 3):

[Equatec](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler) supports .NET CF 3.5

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a memory profiler: "The EQATEC Profiler is a code profiler, not a memory profiler. So it's all about making your app run faster, not about tracking objects and memory."

Comment: FWIW, Eqatec was purchased by Telerik, rolled into JustTrace and CF support was dropped (sadly).  So we're back to pretty much no good solution.

Answer (score 2):

The [CLR Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx) also comes with the CF-SDK, and allows to view the heap of a process. In contrast to [Remote Performance Monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048939/memory-profiler-for-net-compact-framework/1049258#1049258) it doesn't crash all the time ;-)

Comment: The CLR Profiler always shows an error message saying "invalid parameter 'index'" when trying to download the heap dump. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: There is a hotfix / workaround for the crashes of the Remote Performance Monitor. I wrote about it here: http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2012/12/27/finding-memory-leaks-in-.net-compact-framework-applications.aspx