# .NET application memory usage Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, compact-framework

I've got a C# application running on Windows CE smart device and I recently added a new graphing option which results in a "OutOfMemory" exception after running for a few hours. How do I find what is going wrong? The code looks fine, its based on one of the previous graphing options that runs for weeks without a problem.

I've tried the Debug > Windows > Memory options in VS 2005, but they all give the message "Unavailable when debuggee is running." I've also tried attaching to the process using the remote debugging tools (specifically the Windows CE Remote Process Viewer), but there's not enough functionality to see what I'm looking for.

Are there tools in VS 2005 to analyse either a remote C# app or one running locally (ie. Win32)?

Comment: You could try [the 14-day free trial of Redgate's Ants memory analyser](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/). Not sure if it supports CE tho.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Thanks, am about to send an email to their sales team to ask whether it supports WinCE, VS2005, etc. Have you had experience of this product?

Comment: Good grief, why the vote down?

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Just had an email response from Red Gate and they don't target the CF version of .NET, so unfortunately Ants isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

a) see [Memory profiler for .NET Compact Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048939/memory-profiler-for-net-compact-framework)

b) see CF remote performance and ... viewer: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13442&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True

looks like you have a memory leak in code.